# WebBrowser Refresh dosen't refresh PDF zoom level

Tags: browser, pdf

I am using a **WebBrowser** control inside a **WPF** application.

I am accesing some PDF Files located on a server.

The files are opened with the **Adobe Reader extension** for Internet Explorer.

My problem is this: If I zoom on a pdf file when I refresh the webBrowser , the PDF file **doesn't** come back to its default zoom level.

I tried:

1. Navigating to a different page and coming back again
2. Refresh page with cache cleaning

Thank you in advance for all your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension opens a Adobe Acrobat instance and that takes control on how to display the PDF. If you want to reset the zoom level you will probably have to use the API of that extension to do so. On other systems, if you're not tying it down, other PDF viewers might be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

After [Seth](https://superuser.com/a/1423661/1019585)'s reply I found the following way to do it:

I made a button that sends **Ctrl + 2** to the browser. (Adobe Reader's shortcut for "Fit to page") .

This fixed my issue.